# How to iterate over worksheets in workbook, openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been using the openpyxl module to do some processing on some .xlsx files. I've been trying to figure out how to iterate over sheets in a workbook. I'm not sure if I can get it figured out. I've tried the 2 codes below which both return empty results. My .xlsx file has about 20 sheets, so something should return.

The one thing I couldn't find on the internet, is how to set a workbook to an actual workbook. Usually I am writing to a workbook, so I just initialize it by setting a variable to en empty workbook `workbook = Workbook()` but in this case, I am unsure if I can open a workbook by doing `workbook = Workbook(r"C:\Excel\LOOKUP_TABLES_edited.xlsx")`

If anyone can identify what it is I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
workbook = Workbook(r"C:\Excel\LOOKUP_TABLES_edited.xlsx")

for sheet in workbook.worksheets:
    print sheet

# or

for sheet in workbook.worksheets:
    print sheet.title
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Open the workbook via [load_workbook()](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) and iterate over `worksheets`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r"C:\Excel\LOOKUP_TABLES_edited.xlsx")

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    print(sheet)
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's one if you need active worksheets for your code

```
for sheet in wb:
    ws = wb[sheet]
    print('Now in sheet: ' + ws.title)
```

Answer (score 4):

To print titles of all sheets in a workbook:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r"C:\Excel\LOOKUP_TABLES_edited.xlsx")
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled a bit with the whole "workbook.active" and didn't know how to get around it so I tried a little bit of everything and here is what worked well for me!

```
for sheet in workbook.sheetnames[2:len(workbook.sheetnames)]:
     ws = workbook[value]
     for val in ws.iter_rows(min_row=11, max_row=21, min_col=2, max_col=10, values_only=True):
          print(str(sheet) + " " + str(val))
```

This will print the sheet name starting with the third sheet, since that's what I needed, as well as all the cell values referenced. The only other thing is this prints a list and if you want to iterate through each value and pull out "0s" or "None" values, then you'll need another loop. Hope this helps whoever else is looking!