# read and write in excel file with python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to read the cell of a excel file in python, change its value and save it. If I do not have the line `from xlutils.copy import copy` in code, it recognizes `workbook.sheeets()`, but otherwise it says

```sh
    AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'sheets'
```

Here is my code:

```py
    from xlutils.copy import copy

    import xlrd
    st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid;')
    rb = xlrd.open_workbook('00-17.xlsx')

    workbook = copy(rb)
    for sheet in workbook.sheets():
        for row in range(sheet.nrows):

            current_value = sheet.cell(row,3).value
            if(current_value == '1' ) :
                st.pattern.pattern_fore_colour = 5

                for column in [0,2,3]:
                    value = sheet.cell(row, column).value

                    print value
                    sheet.write(row, column, value,st)
    workbook.save('1.xlsx')
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'get_sheet_by_name'

Comment: You may want to go ahead and read the documentation for `xlrd` first. The method for accessing a sheet by name is `.sheet_by_name` not `.get_sheet_by_name`. Also, to get row counts, just use `sheet.nrows`.

Comment: Looks as if you're mixing xlwt and openpyxl.

Comment: You can try this alternative method for read sheet: sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()    xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have to use load_workbook() method first. Check out the link [Print Excel workbook using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751142/print-excel-workbook-using-python) it will probably help.

Can you try doing it with `workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('00-17.xlsx')` and remove the line `workbook = copy(rb)`?

Comment: My python has a problem with load_workbook(), and because it does not finde the base package (although I installed it). Could you have a look at my update?

Comment: Can you try doing it with `workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('00-17.xlsx')` and remove the line `workbook = copy(rb)`?